# How can I target every other iframe using css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to target every other iframe in the screenshot below.

[image]

Can I use nth-child for this? Maybe something like the code below (although this doesn't work)?

`#main iframe:nth-child(2n+2)`

Comment: What do you want to do with the iframe? You won't be able to access their content, just the iframes themselves

Comment: Have you tried `:nth-child()`? It should work with the iframe itself, but not any content in it.

Comment: @Pekka I'm not trying to access the content. I just want to add styles to every other iframe. Why the vote down?

Comment: @John ah, fair enough. (Downvote is not mine) basically, you should be able to use `nth-child(2n+2)` for this. What property are you trying to change?

Comment: @Pekka What would go in between the parenthesis of `nth-child()`? I can never figure this part out.

Comment: @John `2n+2` should be fine. What properties are you trying to style?

Comment: @Pekka I just want to get rid of the right margin for every other iframe. I tried `#main iframe:nth-child(2n+2) { margin-right:0 }` but it gets rid of the right margin for all iframes.

Comment: Could you paste the text in as text so it is readable a screenshot can't have its size altered so is not readable as it is too small

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With that exact HTML structure, you need this selector:

```
#main iframe:nth-child(4n+2)
```

If you'd prefer to start from the first `iframe` instead of the second, remove the `+2`.

Comment: No problem. I've removed the `:not(table)` part because it wasn't required.

Comment: Alternatively, `#main iframe:nth-of-type(odd)` (or `even`).